# How to disable style changing of the input tag when I mouse-over an autocomplete item in chrome?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

I have the following problem. I have a login form with autocomplete enabled. But when the user clicks an empty text-input field (a dropdown pops up with suggested usernames) and then when the user hovers over one of the usernames in the dropdown, the styling of the text-input field becomes vertically bigger by a few pixels screwing up my page. I tried google searching to find how to style this behavior but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too I fixed it by setting a 
height
min-height and you could even set a 
max-height to realy lock it in place

of course everything has to be the same number for example:
height: 40px;
min-height: 40px;
max-height: 40px;

Comment: I tried setting the height. But still, when I hover over the input field the box becomes a few pixels smaller than when I hover over one of the suggested items.

Comment: ah sorry try min-height

Comment: Same problem with min-height. The font seems to change too. By the way I am using Chrome 75.0.3770.100. In IE the problem is less apparent, as the total height doesnt change but the font and the "shadow" inside the box still does.

Comment: Ahh It works better now. I made the box a little bigger vertically and the sizing problem went away after applying the min-height. The font problem is still there. I wonder if it's possible to style this somehow.

Comment: did you set a font-size maybe that will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a max-width in your input. This way, when you hover an autocomplete option, your input won't become bigger than the value setted in your max-width.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken in my original post. The box gets larger vertically not horizontally. I corrected it now.